# How can I get my Facebook open graph image to display in the large format?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, image-size

[According to Facebook](http://jaredlindzon.com/wp-content/themes/jared/img/icons/site/og.jpg), open graph images that are sized 600 x 315 should display in the large format.

I've sized my image to be 1400 x 700 and yet it still displays in the small format.

These are the meta tags I am using:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:description" content="My description" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://thenameofmysite.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://thenameofmysite.com/img/og.jpg" />
```

What am I missing?

Buzzfeed posts on Facebook display the large format correctly. I noticed on their site they have these meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="625" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="415" />
```

I see these meta tags documented [here](http://ogp.me/) but they are apparently optional. Do they have anything to do with the preview image size?

Comment: This might have something to do with whether the shared article becomes featured or not.